# Beautiful Soup For loop gives me individual list, however in need a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying scrap data using beautiful soup, however it comes in the form of the lists, however i need a pandas data frame. I am using a for loop to get the data however i am unable to append these to dataframe. When i check for the len of row it says only 1.

```
INFY = url.urlopen("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/INFY.NS/history?p=INFY.NS")
div = INFY.read()
div = soup(div,'html.parser')
div = div.find("table",{"class":"W(100%) M(0)"})
table_rows = div.findAll("tr")
print(table_rows)

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.findAll('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

Below is the result i get after running the code.

```
['30-Mar-2017', '1,034.00', '1,035.90', '1,020.25', '1,025.50', '1,010.02', '60,78,590']
['29-Mar-2017', '1,034.30', '1,041.50', '1,025.85', '1,031.85', '1,016.27', '34,90,593']
['28-Mar-2017', '1,031.50', '1,039.00', '1,030.05', '1,035.15', '1,019.52', '23,98,398']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.DataFrame([[i.text for i in tr.findAll('td')] for tr in table_rows])
```

You would then need to convert text values to their numeric equivalents.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked. :). I have been struggling with this for last 2 days.